# How do I use OSX Coda to SFTP over an existing SSH connection?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, sftp, coda

I have two servers, an administration server and a web server. The web server is only accessible by the administration server. I can for instance SSH into my administration server and then SSH into my web server through my administration server.

I would like to use the Coda editor by Panic to update files on my web server but have been unable to utilize SFTP through an existing SSH connection. I thought Coda SFTP might work if I connected to my administration server first via the SSH terminal built into Coda but it looks like Coda SFTP simply opens a new shell and tries to access my web server directly instead of routing requests through the existing SSH terminal.

Anyone know how I can do one of the following:
a) Make Coda SFTP use an existing SSH terminal where I can login to my administration server first.
b) Temporarily have all SSH shells on my OSX machine auto-login to my administration server first before taking commands. This would need to be something I could toggle.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a proxy ssh connection to your administration server and then set it up as a proxy through the system preferences panel -> network. From there you should be able to connect to your web server with SFTP like you would normally do

You can create a SOCKS proxy with ssh like this:

```
ssh -D 9999 username@ip-address-of-ssh-server
```

your proxy will then be at localhost port 9999